# MySQL statement not including Null values

Tags: mysql, left-join

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    CAST(`t1`.`ImportedOn` AS DATE) AS `DispatchDate`,
    `t1`.`Order` AS `order`,
    `t1`.`Operation` AS `QbOP`,
    `t1`.`UserOpStatus` AS `OpsAway`,
    `t1`.`UnloadingPoint` AS `Location`,
    `t1`.`WorkCenter` AS `QbWC`,
    `t1`.`LatestStartDate` AS `QbStartDay`,
    `t1`.`LatestStartTime` AS `QbStartTime`,
    `t2`.`Operation` AS `RcOP`,
    `t2`.`WorkCenter` AS `RcWC`,
    `t2`.`LatestStartDate` AS `lateststartdate`,
    `t2`.`LatestStartTime` AS `lateststarttime`,
    `wc`.`CellName` AS `CellName`,
    IF((`wooc`.`ConfirmationDate` IS NULL),
        'Open',
        IF((`t1`.`UserOpStatus` = 'run'),
            'Running',
            'Done')) AS `Status`
FROM
    (((`workorderoperationschedule` `t1`
    LEFT JOIN `workorderoperationschedule` `t2` ON (((`t1`.`Order` = `t2`.`Order`)
        AND (`t2`.`Operation` > `t1`.`Operation`)
        AND (`t2`.`Operation` < (`t1`.`Operation` + 11)))))
    LEFT JOIN `workcenters` `wc` ON ((`wc`.`WorkCenter` = `t1`.`WorkCenter`)))
    LEFT JOIN `workorderoperationconfirmations` `wooc` ON (((`wooc`.`Order` = `t1`.`Order`)
        AND (`wooc`.`Operation` = `t1`.`Operation`))))
WHERE
    ((`t1`.`LatestStartDate` <= CAST(`t1`.`ImportedOn` AS DATE))
        AND (`t1`.`ImportedOn` = (SELECT 
            MAX(`t1`.`ImportedOn`)
        FROM
            `workorderoperationschedule` `t1`))
        AND (`t2`.`ImportedOn` = (SELECT 
            MAX(`t1`.`ImportedOn`)
        FROM
            `workorderoperationschedule` `t1`)))
ORDER BY `Status` DESC , `t1`.`WorkCenter` , `t2`.`LatestStartDate` , `t2`.`LatestStartTime`
```

My challenge is that sometimes t2 will not have a value, which is expected, however, i think MySQL is not returning those rows when t2 has not match.  I thought a left join would return all values from t1 and only the values from t2 that match but that is not happening

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The predicate:

```
`t2`.`ImportedOn` = (SELECT MAX(`t1`.`ImportedOn`) 
                     FROM `workorderoperationschedule` `t1`)
```

in the `WHERE` clause is silently converting your `LEFT JOIN` into an `INNER JOIN`.

To make the left join work you need to move this predicate to the `ON` clause when joinining `t2`.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

If you need  a left join  then you can't use a colunm of a left joined table in a where condition  so try move the t2 condition for max value in the related ON clause

```
 SELECT DISTINCT
    CAST(`t1`.`ImportedOn` AS DATE) AS `DispatchDate`,
    `t1`.`Order` AS `order`,
    `t1`.`Operation` AS `QbOP`,
    `t1`.`UserOpStatus` AS `OpsAway`,
    `t1`.`UnloadingPoint` AS `Location`,
    `t1`.`WorkCenter` AS `QbWC`,
    `t1`.`LatestStartDate` AS `QbStartDay`,
    `t1`.`LatestStartTime` AS `QbStartTime`,
    `t2`.`Operation` AS `RcOP`,
    `t2`.`WorkCenter` AS `RcWC`,
    `t2`.`LatestStartDate` AS `lateststartdate`,
    `t2`.`LatestStartTime` AS `lateststarttime`,
    `wc`.`CellName` AS `CellName`,
    IF((`wooc`.`ConfirmationDate` IS NULL),
        'Open',
        IF((`t1`.`UserOpStatus` = 'run'),
            'Running',
            'Done')) AS `Status`
FROM
    (((`workorderoperationschedule` `t1`
    LEFT JOIN `workorderoperationschedule` `t2` ON (((`t1`.`Order` = `t2`.`Order`)
        AND (`t2`.`Operation` > `t1`.`Operation`)
        AND (`t2`.`Operation` < (`t1`.`Operation` + 11)))))
        AND (`t2`.`ImportedOn` = (SELECT 
            MAX(`t1`.`ImportedOn`)
        FROM
            `workorderoperationschedule` `t1`))
    LEFT JOIN `workcenters` `wc` ON ((`wc`.`WorkCenter` = `t1`.`WorkCenter`)))
    LEFT JOIN `workorderoperationconfirmations` `wooc` ON (((`wooc`.`Order` = `t1`.`Order`)
        AND (`wooc`.`Operation` = `t1`.`Operation`))))
WHERE
    ((`t1`.`LatestStartDate` <= CAST(`t1`.`ImportedOn` AS DATE))
        AND (`t1`.`ImportedOn` = (SELECT 
            MAX(`t1`.`ImportedOn`)
        FROM
            `workorderoperationschedule` `t1`))
        AND (`t2`.`ImportedOn` = (SELECT 
            MAX(`t1`.`ImportedOn`)
        FROM
            `workorderoperationschedule` `t1`)))
ORDER BY `Status` DESC , `t1`.`WorkCenter` , `t2`.`LatestStartDate` , `t2`.`LatestStartTime`


WHERE
    ((`t1`.`LatestStartDate` <= CAST(`t1`.`ImportedOn` AS DATE))
        AND (`t1`.`ImportedOn` = (SELECT 
            MAX(`t1`.`ImportedOn`)
        FROM
            `workorderoperationschedule` `t1`))
        )
```

Comment: Yep, that'll do it. I was too lazy to copy the whole thing myself.

Comment: Thank you!  That helps illustrate it